# Creating a truststore to only validate certificate signed by a custom CA in JAVA

Tags: java, android, ssl, certificate, truststore

I hope this isn't a duplicate.
I'm currently working on client server game based on netty with a client on Android. I'm trying to make a secure login process so I tryed using ssl on top of java socket.

I managed to create a self-signed certificate and to use SSL. The problem is that the example source code i found use à custom TrustManagerFactory which doesn't make any check upon certificate validity. Since I don't wan't to allow Man In The Middle attack i searched for more information on SSL handshake and here is what i understood:

1. To initiate SSL session, the client send a request to the server.
2. The server which own the certificate(.jks or .bks) extract public informations into a X509 certificate and send it to the client.
3. The client check for the validity of the certificate ( In my current solution do nothing)
4. If check succed retrieve the server's public key from the certificate, generate a random key, encrypt it with the public key and sends it to the server.
5. The server use his private key to decrypt the randomly generated key.
6. Both client and server now share the same random key and they start a comunication using this key for symetric encryption ( like AES ).

I don't need to accept certificate from anyone else than my own server so i thought about 2 solution:

1. Save the X509 on client side and create à custom TrustManager witch only accept this certificate. This solution seems easy to implement but rather hard to maintain since every certificate change on server side would need to update X509 certificate on every client.
2. Create my own CA certificate sign my ssl certificate with this certificate and manage somehow to tel my client to only trust all certificate signed with my CA.

What i understood about CA authentification is this :

1. A CA root certificate is a normal certificate that contain a key pair.
2. signing a certificate with a CA mean adding at the end of the being-signed certificate a hash of the whole certificate encrypted with the CA private key.
3. this signature is contained in the X509 certificate along with some informations about CA.
4. To check certificate validity, the client generate certificate hash and compare it to the decrypted hash (using CA public key) contained in the X509 certificate.

So if i'm not mistaking in all of this, if i want to implement my second solution, I need to provide a CA certificate to the client so that he can check certificates. I've seen that it is possible to init à TrustManager with a truststore. I asume it must be a different certificate from the root CA one since the whole security of this depends on my CA private key 's confidentiality. So my questions are :

1. What should this client truststore contain and how to generate if from my root CA ??
2. I have red that ssl engine is broken for self signed certificate. So is my second solutions viable on android?
3. If this can work, how can i invalidate my certificate if i see that someone manage to get my private key somehow? I have red things about crl but i don't know how to generate/use them in my truststore?

thanks in advance.

Comment: Steps 4-5 are not correct. The client does not generate the session key; does not encrypt it; and does not send it. It is negotiated via a key agreement protocol.

Answer (score 0):

I can only answer part of your questions:

1. The truststore should contain your CA, you can generate it with keytool:
   http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19509-01/820-3503/6nf1il6er/index.html
2. No problem you can implement this in android in the same way than in java using java.security.* and org.apache.http.* classes. One warning, for android versions <=2.3, you could need to implement a workaround as some public CA are missing and it doesn't support miss-ordered certificates chains. I can give you more details if needed.
3. I don't know

**Edit:**
A good turorial:
http://nelenkov.blogspot.com/2011/12/using-custom-certificate-trust-store-on.html

Comment: Thanks! I'll try on keytool commands provided in you link as soon as I can. I'm not realy sure to understand the problem with Android <=2.3. My project doesn't need public CA. Since I dont use http and open socket only with my server. I plan do use a Java trustManager accepting only certificate signed with my own CA. Will I still encounter this issue ? If yes i would be very thanksfull if you could provide me some information about this workaround you are talking about.

Comment: You shouldn't encounter any problem with a private CA as you will not have the problem of the trusted authority CA missing on the device and your certificate chain should be right. If you later use a public certificate the solution consist of including your public CA in your truststore and to use a custom X509TrustManager reordering your CA chain and a custom SocketFactory. I can give you the code when needed. I added a link to a good tutorial.